Add Properties Toolbar next to viewer
I am trying to add a fixed properties tab to the right side of my screen. Sadly I am unable to force the Viewer to the left 80% of my screen. Therefore my properties panel is hiding the right 20% of my viewer.
I tried to force the two elements in place with styling, but with no success. The viewer always uses up 100% of the Screen and is therefore partially hidden.
My Code:
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    body, html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #forgeViewer {
      flex: 1;
      width: 80%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #f0f0f0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #propertyPanel {
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
  <div id="propertyPanel">
    <h2>Properties</h2>
    <div id="propertyContent"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var viewer;
  var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
    api: 'streamingV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'streamingV2_EU'
    getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
      var token = '<My Access Token>';
      var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by APS Authentication (OAuth) API
      onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
    }
  };

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
      console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
      return;
    }

    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

    var documentId = 'urn:<My URN>';
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
      var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
      viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    }

    function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
      console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
    }


    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function(event) {
      const dbIds = event.dbIdArray;
      if (dbIds.length > 0) {
        viewer.getProperties(dbIds[0], function(props) {
          displayProperties(props);
        });
      } else {
        clearProperties();
      }
    });

    function displayProperties(props) {
      const propertyContent = document.getElementById('propertyContent');
      propertyContent.innerHTML = '';
      for (const prop of props.properties) {
        const propDiv = document.createElement('div');
        propDiv.innerHTML = `<strong>${prop.displayName}</strong>: ${prop.displayValue}`;
        propertyContent.appendChild(propDiv);
      }
    }

    function clearProperties() {
      const propertyContent = document.getElementById('propertyContent');
      propertyContent.innerHTML = '<p>No properties available</p>';
    }



  });

</script>
</body>

The Result:
how it looks
As you can see the view Cube in the top right corner is fully hidden behind the properties tab. I only managed to get the desired results by manually changing the css in the website dev-tools:
how i want it to look

When you don't add position: relative; to the parent element (e.g., forgeviewer), the child elements won't correctly calculate their width based on the parent. Adding position: relative; creates a positioning context, ensuring that the child elements use the parent element as a reference for their size and position.
Here is the correct code and the result:
 #forgeViewer {
      flex: 1;
      width: 80% ;
      height: 100%;
      background: #f0f0f0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      position:relative;
    }

codepen capture

Yes, similar to this https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-does-not-stay-its-container
